# jQuery Cycle plugin - multiple simple slideshows / instances on one-page website

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle, jquery-isotope, custom-data-attribute

I'm working on a one-page website using David De Sandro's jQuery Isotope plugin. In 7 Isotope elements, I'm running the Cycle slideshow plugin in a basic fashion (no clicking, pagination, pause, hover, etc.). It works - but I'm suspecting I've implemented this not very effectively.

HTML (one of 7 Isotope elements)

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="slideshow preview1">
  <img src="media/cl_t_preview_0.jpg" />
  <img src="media/cl_t_preview_1.jpg" />
  <img src="media/cl_t_preview_2.jpg" />
  </div>
</div> // and 6 more...
```

CSS (for all 7 slideshows)

```
.slideshow.preview1, .slideshow.preview2, .slideshow.preview3, .slideshow.preview4, .slideshow.preview5, .slideshow.preview6, .slideshow.preview7 {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
height: 252px;
width: 252px;
}
.slideshow.preview1 img, .slideshow.preview2 img, .slideshow.preview3 img, .slideshow.preview4 img, .slideshow.preview5 img, .slideshow.preview6 img, .slideshow.preview7 img {
display: block;
}
```

JS (7 instances - this is repetitive and ineffective)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.slideshow.preview1').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollHorz',
    random: 1,
    speed: 300,
    timeout: 6000,
    delay: -1000
});
    $('.slideshow.preview2').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollHorz',
    random: 1,
    speed: 300,
    timeout: 6000,
    delay: -2000
}); // and five more calls...
});
```

So, how can I make the JS part more effective than just doggedly repeating it 7 times over as I'm doing it now? Somehow, I should pass just the class names and the 7 different delay values...

[Here](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int.html) Michael Malsup uses a technique with tables (that I don't understand) to hand over the necessary parameters via the HTML itself. Is that the best way? I just saw the use of HTML5 data-attributes; maybe that's the best-practice-way to remove my JS redundancies?

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="slideshow preview" data-delay="-2000"> // each occurrence has its own delay
      <img src="media/prevslide_3.jpg" alt="Img 1" />
      <img src="media/prevslide_4.jpg" alt="Img 2" />
      <img src="media/prevslide_5.jpg" alt="Img 3" />
  </div>
</div>

$('.slideshow.preview').cycle({ // and the call needs to occur only once
fx: 'scrollHorz',
random: 1,
speed: 300,
timeout: 6000,
delay: -2000 // but how to pass the data-delay value in here?
});
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Solved by user Musa here http://stackoverflow.com/a/11335463/963514

Comment: Much less code redundancy with this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11341493/963514 approach