# Evaluate a data-attibute on a div with jQuery and pass the value into a function

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I have multiple slideshow blocks with preview images (for jQuery Cycle, each slideshow instance with a different delay in milliseconds) like this:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="slideshow preview" data-delay="-2000">
        <img src="media/prevslide_3.jpg" alt="Img 1" />
        <img src="media/prevslide_4.jpg" alt="Img 2" />
        <img src="media/prevslide_5.jpg" alt="Img 3" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to use jQuery to pass these varying delay values (set via data-attribute)into the function that will run all occurences of Cycle.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.slideshow.preview').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollHorz',
    random: 1,
    speed: 300,
    timeout: 6000,
    // here, for a single slideshow, delay is set like this "delay: -1234"
});
});
```

How does one evaluate the data-attribute on the div - data-delay="-2000" - and passes it into the Cycle function?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this ...., delay: $(this).attr('data-delay'); ... i did'nt try but may be this approch can help you.

Comment: @Rune FS: I tried to use delay: { $('.slideshow.preview').attr('data-delay'); } in there, but that obviously gives a syntax error; so I presume having to somehow evaluate the data-delay attribute into a variable and "somehow" associate it with the required "delay:" option of the plugin?

Comment: @Kerberos: yes, maybe I have to create a variable var delay = $(this).attr('data-delay'); in there and then apply it to the "delay:" setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has the [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5) method which works with the html5 data attributes.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideshow.preview').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollHorz',
        random: 1,
        speed: 300,
        timeout: 6000,
        delay: $(".slideshow.preview").data("delay")
    });
});
```

EDIT

I missed the delay key, but this works.
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/paWej/)

Comment: Thank you very much, this evaluates the data-delay attribute correctly. But now all slideshows start at the same time - as if only the first slideshow's div's data-attribute is evaluated and used on all others...

Comment: If there are multiple slide shows and they require different delays you may have to call them individually, `$(".slideshow.preview").data("delay")` only takes the first match element and use its `data-delay`

Comment: Ah, thanks, just saw your fiddle. Changed it to show what I mean that there's no different delay between different slideshows. Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/6mU9S/3/

Comment: Ok, thanks, I see what you mean. As jQuery beginner, I was under the impression that there would be a better way than to do it like the plug-in creator who at http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int.html with

$.fn.cycle.defaults.timeout = 6000;
$(function() {
$('td pre code').each(function() {
eval($(this).text());
});
});

evaluates the settings for multiple slideshows that are put into the HTML with <pre><code> tags. Somehow I thought doing the same with jQuery is the better way to achieve the same functionality.

Comment: To set delays based on the `div` of each slideshow you'll have to set ids to uniquely identify these elements. http://jsfiddle.net/6mU9S/4/

Comment: I see, that is the working solution. It also simplifies multiple uses of the Cycle plugin on one page. Thank you very much for your time and explanations; this has helped me a lot!

Comment: Much less code redundancy with this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11341493/963514 approach