# Using jQuery's .each() function to attach a function to multiple slideshow containers

Tags: jquery, function, cycle, each

I have very many small jQuery Cycle slideshow divs (containers) on a one-page website like

```
    <div class="foo bar" data-value="1000"> // data-value varies on each container
        <img src="directory/img_0.jpg" alt="img 0" />
        <img src="directory/img_1.jpg" alt="img 1" />
        <img src="directory/img_2.jpg" alt="img 2" />
    </div>
```

and want to cycle them all - **with each slideshow div having a different data-value** - without hard coding/repeating

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.foo.bar').cycle({
      speed: 300,
      timeout: 6000,
      delay: $('.foo.bar').data('value')
  });
});
```

for all occurences of such slideshow div. How can I "attach" or "bind" or "link" such jQuery function to each slideshow div so that each element's differing data-value is used? I suspect that jQuery's .each() function could allow me to do so - but how?

EDIT [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6mU9S/6/)

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention, `.each()` will let you do this quite easily:

```
$('.foo.bar').each(function() {
    $(this).cycle({
      speed: 300,
      timeout: 6000,
      delay: $(this).data('value')
    });
});
```

Inside the `.each` callback, `this` refers to the element you are currently operating on.

Comment: Thank you very much - that works as intended http://jsfiddle.net/6mU9S/13/ I did not know that it was that straightforward; back to jQuery preschool for me, positive vote for you ;)